# .value() called from iterator causes an Appcrash

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code, in which I want to find in a QMap the value associated with the key which equals "tagName".
Once I have the iterator positionned at the right place, I want to fetch this value (should be a QVector of QStrings) to see if I can find what I want inside of it.

But whenever I try to do p.value(), my program crashes.
I checked my debugger, weird thing is that key and value for p are shown as "inaccessible" in the debug panel...

```
QMap<QString, QVector<QString> >::iterator p = associations.find(tagName);

int index = p.value().indexOf(noteName);

return (index != -1);
```

Any help or hints will be appreciated!

Comment: You should first check whether the iterator is valid, i.e. whether you found something in the map.

Comment: `if ( p == associations.end() ) return;`.

Comment: Never, ever, ever write `if (bool_expr) return true; else return false;`. It's identical to `return bool_expr;`, only longer.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Yep sorry, I'm quite tired, I would have noticed otherwise, quite ashamed right now!

Comment: @Selphira: Don't sweat it. I occasionally tear my hair out reading code I wrote six months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the iterator is valid, i.e. whether you found something in the map, before dereferencing it:

```
return p != associations.end() && p.value().indexOf(noteName) != -1;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this indeed does stop the program from crashing, so right now I'm facing another problem : my variable associations (my QMap) does contain a key/value pair corresponding to the tagName key (I checked this already while debugging) so how come the "find" call can't seem to find it?

Comment: @Selphira that is bacically not possible, so you have another problem which we cannot see in the code you posted.

Comment: @juanchopanzaz Okay, so I really was mistaking, you're right. Your comment made me think about it a bit more, and it turns out what I thought was passed as parameter (my tagName) was not what I thought it was. I was searching for my mistake in the wrong place. Anyway, this answer and all the comments allowed me to solve my issue, so thanks!